# Is there any way to make a window transparent macOS Mojave?

Tags: mojave, window-manager

I liked the feature in Linux where you could simply turn a window transparent. I also had an app for Windows that did it, called [Peek Through](http://www.lukepaynesoftware.com/projects/peek-through/) that did it. I finally came back to macOS and now I want a similar feature. I don't know the Swift/C langs, but I know the command line pretty well (kinda rusty, my short stint with windows didn't help any). I have seen the "Deskovery" app but I don't want to pay money for it. I have seen the old app "afloat" but I am pretty sure that doesn't work on newer computers. I am on a MacBook Pro 8,1 running macOS Mojave. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think the closest thing in macOS is to minimize the window (Command + M). You can also Hide the window (Command + H).

Comment: Yes, but I would like to make it transparent.... There must be some bash command, right?

Comment: What do you mean by transparent? I am pretty sure there is no Bash command to do this. I think the best option is still to Hide the Window using Command + H.

Comment: I mean make it semi-transparent. take a look at the mentioned app for windows. It just allows you to see through the selected app while still keeping the app above the other one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174918/how-to-get-window-with-semi-transparent-blurred-background

Comment: @Todd yes, kinda. Close enough, can you put an answer so I can close this?

Comment: Ok, I put in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a post that uses Swift/Objective-C code to create a semi-transparency thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174918/how-to-get-window-with-semi-transparent-blurred-background.

Comment: How can you use this to make an existing window semi-transparent?

Comment: The OP says it works so I guess it fits their needs.